# Atribuir valor de um banco de dados para uma variavel php

Tags: php

a variável `$query` aparentemente fica vazia pois não adiciona valor nenhum no banco de dados.

Onde estou errando?

```
$aVar = mysqli_connect('localhost');
$query = mysqli_query($aVar, "SELECT MAX(id_evento) FROM eventos2");

$sql->bindValue(':idp',$query);
```

Comment: A função `mysqli_connect()` deveria receber 4 parâmetros neh não? host, user, password e database.

Answer (score -2):

Se a sua intenção é recuperar o último registro da tabela, você pode tentar da seguinte forma:

```
<?
$host     = "localhost";
$user     = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "nome_do_banco_de_dados";
$dblink = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Erro ao conectar com o banco de dados: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
$sqlquery = "SELECT MAX(id_evento) as codigo FROM eventos2";
if ($result = mysqli_query($dblink, $sqlquery)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["codigo"];
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($dblink);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde caro tenho algumas sugestões.

Primeiramente a instancia da conexão é chamada da seguinte forma

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

ref:https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

De qualquer forma parece que voce quer usar o resultado de uma busca como parâmetro para outro comando sql

```
$sql->bindValue(':idp',$query);
```

Minha recomendação é que use **subquery** que funciona em qualquer SGBD, como no caso do sqlserver : https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15

Exemplo 1:

```
"INSERT INTO tabela1 (id,nome) VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tabela1) + 1, 'Nome')"
```

Exemplo 2:

```
"UPDATE tabela1 
SET nome = (SELECT nomeCompleto FROM pessoa WHERE pessoa.id = tabela1.id_pessoa)"
```